# Get a OneDrive file with PowerAutomate from sharing link or url

Tags: sharepoint, onedrive, power-automate

Here is what I'm trying to do :

From a Power Automate, I'm getting the shareable link of the Microsoft Teams Record meeting and the ID of the meeting

The Flow must take the file from OneDrive, and move it to another cloud repository

The problem is that I can't find a way to get the file content (or name) from the link, in either Power Automate or PowerApps.

Another alternative is to create a flow for each file created in the OneDrive Folder, but with this solution I'm unable to get the related meeting or Idmeeting of the recording.

Comment: This is very interesting. What is your approach so far? Can you show your flow?

If I'm correct, once you open the link in a browser, it resolves to [company sharepoint url]/onedrive.aspx?id=SOME_ID where "SOME_ID" contains the path to the file, apparently.

I think it might be possible to use that url to access onedrive.

Comment: @carlosherrera I have been solved it by using Microsoft graph, specifically driveItem https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0

with that, I could obtain metadata and the specific URL of the file.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the "Parse JSON" function to get the name of the new file.  I've used the instructions in this video although still having troubles with my own flow, which is a little more complicated.  Maybe you'll have more luck.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UKuzX8zlnuE

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).